# How to configure WCF With Static IP Address?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a windows server 2012 with installed IIS on it.
I want to public my WCF to this IIS, 
I dont know how to config `web.config` file with static IP Address.
I have searched on internet, but no results match for me.

This is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="basicHttp" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"  maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"  maxArrayLength="200000000"  maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
          <service name="MyService.BService">

            <endpoint address="http://192.168.11.197/MyService/BService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="" contract="MyService.IBService" />
          </service>

        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
              <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      </system.webServer>

    </configuration>
```

Comment: your service is listed there on an IP.. if thats not the IP.. then .. well change it?

Comment: I donI know what you mean, please clarify.. thanks a lot

Comment: I cant clarify further.. It is that simple

Comment: Replace the `192.168.11.197` in the endpoint address with the IP of your box that is hosting the service.